# What does the green rectangle next to questions in the reputation page mean?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation

I noticed a recent change in the "reputation page"; some questions have a green rectangle instead of an indication of the reputation change. E.g., the second question below, and a few others:
[image]

What is that rectangle meant to represent?

**Added.** Thanks to Tim Stone; it seems to be a rendering bug, so I've added the [bug] tag.

Comment: It's a new game: You guess what there is behind the green rectangle, and if your guess is right you gain 10 points. `;-)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It indicates that one of the sources of reputation was your answer being marked as accepted. The reputation value is inside of the rectangle (+25 in the first instance in your screenshot), but there appears to be a stylesheet issue that's preventing the text colour from being changed to white so that it's displayed correctly. It should look like this:

[image: example of reputation indicator with accept status]

In Stack Overflow's stylesheet, `.bounty-indicator-tab` has `color: white !important`, but on the Maths site it seems to not be marked `!important`, so the default green colour is unintentionally taking precedence.

Comment: So, it's a rendering bug? If so, I'll add a bug tag to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yep, it is.

Comment: I don't know how recent this is, but for as long as I was using SE, a green box like that also signifies an awarded bounty.

Answer (score 4):

Jin pushed some CSS loving for this case across all sites - you should be all set with proper white text on the indicator now.

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Thanks for the quick fix!